# Why do I have duplicate rows for the same subscriber in my MSmerge_identity_range table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, merge, replication

I have a database with merge replication set up on a SQL 2005 server with 1 subscriber.  I am having some identity range issues an I started to look at the MSmerge_identity_range table.  I have one subscriber but 2 rows for each.  For Example(I shortend the guids but for arguments sake they are the same for each row):

subid  artid  range_begin  range_end next_range_begin  next_range_end  is_pub_range max_used

FAD8EA4E D8902F8E 1680378 1684378 1684378 1688378 0 NULL
FAD8EA4E D8902F8E 1680378 2147483647 NULL NULL 1 1692379

Why are there 2 rows for one identity range for one subscriber?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The second row has "is_pub_range" flag set and its range_end is int.max, it seems to be used by MS code to determine a new range when the current range (e.g. the first row in your sample) exhausted.